# Implementing Audit trail c#

Tags: c#, .net, audit-trail

i implemented an audit log for every action made in the server (added, modified and delete). The problem occurs in the modified, because i audit every property which was modified, but some properties i don`t want to audit. Ex: Timestamp, or others.
This is what i did, and works fine:
1) I made another SaveChanges() method into DBContext
2)

```
if (dbEntity.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                foreach (string propertyName in dbEntity.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    if (!Equals(dbEntity.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName), dbEntity.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName)))
                    {
                        var log = new AuditLogDetailEntity()
                        {
                            Timestamp = timestamp,
                            Type = "M", // Modified
                            EntityName = tableName1,
                            PrimaryKeyValue = Convert.ToInt32(dbEntity.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(primaryKeyName)),  
                            PropertyName = propertyName,    
                            OldValue = dbEntity.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntity.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString(),
                            NewValue = dbEntity.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntity.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString()
                        };
                        changesCollection.Add(log);
                    }
                }
            }`
```

This is an extract code, not all the funcion.
I could make a validation inside, asking for that fields I don`t want to audit, but, Is there a more thorough way of doing it? Maybe adding some dataannotations in the classes, or something else..
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped] attribute for that.

Comment: How? Which DataAnnotation should i use? Thanks

Comment: Use it like this:  

    class AuditLogDetailEntity  
    {  
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]  
        DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }  
        //etc  
    }

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class UnMappedAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

And then check if each property has it

```
foreach (string propertyName in dbEntity.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
{
    if(!dbEntity.Entity.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UnMappedAttribute), true).Any())
    {
         continue;
    }

    if (!Equals(dbEntity.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName), dbEntity.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName)))
    {
        //.....
    }
}
```